# Mostrar listado de otra tabla en django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Hola a ver si alguien podría ayudarme por favor.
Tengo una modelo llamado Alumno, otro llamado Recibo y otro llamado DetRecibo.
En Recibo hay un campo que se llama alumno_recibo, el cual cuando saca un recibo se guarda el alumno que ha sacado dicho recibo. En DetRecibo que esta relacionado con Recibo hay un campo que se llama activiad_realizada, ese es el campo que me interesa recuperar en la vista de Alumno, concretamente se llama vista Detalle alumno, copio a continuación los modelos, estoy un poco perdido y no se si no tengo hecho bien las tablas o como hacer para sacar esa Actividad que ha pagado el alumno para que se vea en su detalle.

```html
class DatosBasicos(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Nombre', unique=False, null=False, blank=False)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Apellidos', unique=False, null=False, blank=False)
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=400, verbose_name='Dirección', unique=False, null=False, blank=False)
    provincia = models.CharField(choices=Provincia, max_length=120, verbose_name='Provincia', null=True, blank=True)
    localidad = models.CharField(max_length=120, verbose_name='Localidad', null=True, blank=True)
    # phoneNumberRegex = RegexValidator(regex=r"^\+?1?\d{8,15}$", message="Formato del teléfono: '+34999999999'")
    # phoneNumber = models.CharField(validators=[phoneNumberRegex], max_length=16, unique=True)
    telf = PhoneNumberField(unique=False, null=False, blank=False, max_length=12)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=False, null=False, blank=False,)
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField(verbose_name='Fecha de nacimiento', null=False, blank=False)
    actividades = models.ManyToManyField(Actividad, verbose_name='Actividad/es', max_length=250)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Alumno (DatosBasicos):
    cp = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Código Postal', validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,5}$')])
    monitores = models.ManyToManyField(Monitor, verbose_name='Monitor/es', max_length=250)
    pagado = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='alumno/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Foto')
```

Esto sería la tabla Alumno, que hereda de otra, porque comparte con Monitores los datos comunes.

```html
class Recibo(models.Model):
    alumno_recibo = models.ForeignKey(Alumno, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    subtotal = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    iva = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Recibo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Recibos'
        ordering = ['id']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.alumno_recibo.get_full_name()


    def toJSON(self):
        item = model_to_dict(self)
        item['alumno'] = self.alumno_recibo.toJSON()
        item['subtotal'] = format(self.subtotal, '.2f')
        item['iva'] = format(self.iva, '.2f')
        item['total'] = format(self.total, '.2f')
        item['date_joined'] = self.date_joined.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        item['det_hora'] = [{'id': g.id, 'nombre': g.get_horarios_display()} for g in self.detrecibo_set.all()]
        item['det_meses'] = [{'id': g.id, 'nombre': g.get_meses_display()} for g in self.detrecibo_set.all()]
        item['det_actividad'] = [{'id': g.id, 'nombre': g.actividad_realizada.nombre} for g in self.detrecibo_set.all()]
        item['det_dias'] = [{'id': g.id, 'nombre': g.actividad_realizada.dias} for g in self.detrecibo_set.all()]
        item['det_centros'] = [{'id': g.id, 'nombre': g.actividad_realizada.get_centros_display()} for g in self.detrecibo_set.all()]
        # print(item['det_hora'])
        # item['det'] = [i.toJSON() for i in self.detrecibo_set.all()]
        return item


class DetRecibo(models.Model):
    recibo = models.ForeignKey(Recibo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    actividad_realizada = models.ForeignKey(Actividad, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Actividad realizada +')
    meses = MultiSelectField(choices=Meses, verbose_name='Mes/es a pagar', max_length=250)
    horarios = models.CharField(choices=horarios_choices, verbose_name='Horario de la actividad +', max_length=250)
    price = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    subtotal = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.actividad_realizada.nombre

    def toJSON(self):
        item = model_to_dict(self, exclude=['recibo'])
        item['actividad_realizada'] = self.actividad_realizada.toJSON()
        item['nombre'] = self.actividad_realizada.nombre
        item['horarios'] = self.get_horarios_display()
        item['meses'] = self.get_meses_display()
        item['price'] = format(self.price, '.2f')
        item['subtotal'] = format(self.subtotal, '.2f')
        return item
```

La vista la tengo como muestro a continuación, en su html puedo mostrar sin problema todos los campos de su misma tabla, pero a la hora de ver que Actividad ha pagado no consigo saber como sacarla.

```html
class AlumnoDetailsView(LoginRequiredMixin, ValidatePermissionRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Alumno
    success_url = reverse_lazy('general:alumno_datails')
    url_redirect = success_url
    template_name = 'alumno/details.html'
    permission_required = 'general.view_alumno'

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Detalles del Alumnos'
        context['list_url'] = reverse_lazy('general:alumno_list')
        context['entity'] = 'Alumnos'
        return context
```

Si alguien pudiera guiarme por favor.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Hola he conseguido sacar el listado así.

```html
 # data = []
        # for i in Recibo.objects.filter(alumno_recibo_id=self.kwargs['pk']):
        #     data.append(i.toJSON())
        # print(data)
        context = {
                'act_alumno': [{'id': g.id, 'nombre': g.detrecibo_set.all()} for g in Recibo.objects.filter(alumno_recibo_id=self.kwargs['pk'])]
            }
```

Ahora lo que pasa que como es normal un alumno puede sacar diferentes recibos en diferentes meses y la activiadd que realiza estará varias veces, ay que mostrara todas las coincidencias del alumno en el recibo.
Estoy intentando sacar y añadir a un lista las actividades, pero que solo se guarde si no esta repetido, lo hago tal que así, pero no me funciona.

```html
nombre_act = []
        for key, value in context.items():
            for i in value:
                for e in i['nombre']:
                    # print(e)
                    if e in nombre_act:
                        print("repetido")
                    else:
                        nombre_act.append(e)
        print(nombre_act)
```

Por favor alguien puede ayudarme? Saludos

Comment: Esto pareciera ser una nueva pregunta. Por cierto, los snippets solo funcionan para HTML/CSS/JS: el formato debes agregarlo colocando triples acentos graves (```) una línea antes y una después de tu código. De hecho, no se entiende cuál era la pregunta original... Lee [ask], [answer] y haz el [tour] para el funcionamiento del sitio. Por último, no olvides que [es.so] no es un repositorio de código.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas disculpa haber formulado mal la pregunta, pero realmente lo que buscaba era sacar un listado en un modelo llamado Alumno, acceder a otro modelo llamado Recibo y ahí sacar un listado como explico arriba. Luego es verdad que es otra cuestión ya que consigo sacarlo y lo que quiero es que no se agreguen los repetidos, así que disculpa mi torpeza. De todas formas ya lo conseguí, pego el código por si le sirve a alguien.

```html
 def alumno_actividad(self):
        context = {
                'act_alumno': [{'id': g.id, 'nombre': g.detrecibo_set.all()} for g in Recibo.objects.filter(alumno_recibo_id=self.kwargs['pk'])]
            }

nombre_act = []
        for key, value in context.items():
            for i in value:
                for e in i['nombre']:
                    # La variable e tiene todo el detalle del recibo por eso tenemos que acceder a su valor con su nombre para la comprobación
                    e = e.actividad_realizada.nombre
                    if e in nombre_act:
                        # print("esta en la lista")
                        pass
                    else:
                        nombre_act.append(e)
        context = nombre_act
        return context
        
        
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Detalles del Alumnos'
        context['list_url'] = reverse_lazy('general:alumno_list')
        context['entity'] = 'Alumnos'
        context['alumno_actividad'] = self.alumno_actividad()
        return context
```

Así sería el código completo, espero que a alguien le sirva de ayuda también.

Saludos

Comment: "Pego el código por si le sirve a alguien": recuerda que [es.so] _no es un repositorio de código_. Debes explicar cómo funciona, la idea es entender su funcionamiento. Además, los snippets son solo para código HTML/CSS/JS, no para Python. Tu código no se puede ejecutar aquí. Dale el formato correcto agregando triples acentos graves (```) una línea antes y una después del mismo. Y ahora que lo veo: eso fue lo que te dije en la _no-respuesta_ anterior... No hagas caso omiso a los comentarios: edita tanto tu pregunta como tu respuesta final.